# ScalikeJDBC: How to do select or insert query aginst a Postgresql db?

Tags: postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

I have the following SQL code I would to execute against a Postgresql db:

```
    sql"""WITH s AS (
             SELECT id
             FROM $tableName
             WHERE $columnName = $value
         ), i AS (
             INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnName)
            SELECT $value
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT id
                FROM $tableName
                WHERE $columnName = $value
            )
            RETURNING id
         )
         SELECT id
         FROM i
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id
         FROM s
      """
```

If I use `update` or `updateAndRetrieveGeneratedKey` within a `localTx` I get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.`. If I use `single` within `readOnly` I get something like `... cannot perform an insert in a read only query`.
What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: will discuss this question here: https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/issues/996